# how to use reference file as source directory in my current setup

Tags: perl

This is the current code which manually keyin the source directory and destination directory.
https://github.com/klgabs/perl/blob/main/zip_and_move.pl

My objective is to use a refence file a source dir and manipulate the destination dir which is almost the same as the source dir minus the STAGING location

the reference files will look like this below in a txt file.

```
/archives/data/mefab/STAGING/PRODUCTION
/archives/data/bkfb/STAGING/PRODUCTION
/archives/data/sast/STAGING/PRODUCTION
/archives/data/cast/STAGING/PRODUCTION
/archives/data/advan/STAGING/PRODUCTION
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking how to go from

```perl
my $stage = "/archives/data/mefab/STAGING/PRODUCTION";
```

to

```perl
my $prod = "/archives/data/mefab/PRODUCTION";
```

Options:

1. ```perl
   my $prod = "$stage/../../PRODUCTION";
   ```
2. ```perl
   use Cwd qw( abs_path );

   my $prod = abs_path("$stage/../../PRODUCTION");
   ```
3. ```perl
   use Path::Tiny qw( path );

   my $prod = path($stage)->parent(2)->child("PRODUCTION");
   ```

If you don't want to hardcode `PRODUCTION`,

1. ```perl
   use File::Basename qw( basename );

   my $prod = "$stage/../../" . basename($stage);
   ```
2. ```perl
   use Cwd            qw( abs_path );
   use File::Basename qw( basename );

   my $prod = abs_path("$stage/../../" . basename($stage));
   ```
3. ```perl
   use Path::Tiny qw( path );

   $stage = path($stage);
   my $prod = $stage->parent(2)->child($stage->basename());
   ```

---

Alternatively you could start with

```perl
my $base = "/archives/data/mefab";
```

Then all you'd need is

```perl
my $stage = "$base/STAGING/PRODUCTION";
my $prod  = "$base/PRODUCTION";
```